# jQuery: How to check if a value exists in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, arrays

I am trying to write a simple input field validation plugin at the moment *(more of a learning exercise really)* and thought this would not be too hard, seeing as all I should have to do is:

1. Get input fields
2. Store them in array with each one's
   value
3. On submit of form check if array
   contains any empty strings

But I seem to fail at writing something that checks for an empty string *(read: input with no text inside)* inside my array.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var form = $(this), // passed in form element
    inputs = form.find('input'), // all of this forms input fields
    isValid = false; // initially set the form to not be valid


function validate() {
    var fields = inputs.serializeArray(); // make an array out of input fields

    // start -- this does not work
    for (var n in fields) {
        if (fields[n].value == "") {
            isValid = false;
            console.log('failed');
        } else {
            isValid = true;
            console.log('passed');
        };
    }
    // end -- this does not work

}; // close validate()

// TRIGGERS
inputs.live('keyup blur', function(event) {
    validate();
});
```

Any help with how I can check if one of the fields is blank and if so return a `isValid = false` would be much appreciated.

I also played around with the `$.inArray("", fields)` but this would never return 0 or 1 even when the `console.log` showed that the fields had no value.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Just as a side observation, is it necessary to look over *all* input fields when *any* of them change?  Wouldn't you only want to re-validate the input that changed?  Also you probably want `:input` instead of `input` for your selector, if you want to include `<select>` and `<textarea>`.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, scour the API and see what shortcuts you can use. Instead of using a `for..in` loop, you can use `$.each`. Instead of `variable.value` you can use `$(variable).val()`. Basically, use jQuery or get rid of it, because otherwise the readability of the code drops drastically if you're switching between straight JS and jQuery JS. (You'll thank yourself in the end, I promise.)

Comment: I wrote something similar yesterday at http://www.ajgraham.com/2010/05/simple-but-powerful-jquery-form-validation/#core-functions if you want to compare approaches, there is a lot of crossover

Comment: `for..in` is a bad idea. It is used to enumerate an object's properties. A regular `for` loop should be used instead to iterate array values, or the `$.each` that jquery provides.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments! They have been very very helpful. I have now decided to use the `$.each` that jQuery provides and it works great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a more-jQuery style syntax, you could replace your for loop using:

```
var isValid = true;  // default to valid

$.each(fields, function(i, field){
    if(field.value == '') {
        console.log('failed');   
        isValid = false; 
    } else {
        console.log('passed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If the first field is empty, and the second isn't, you'll overwrite the `isValid` variable that way. You can `break;` the for loop once you get the first empty variable.

Comment: Great answer. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: Made it work just like I wanted. Thanks. Ultimately however I feel like the `$.each` approach is probably the better one seeing as this is a jQuery "plugin". Thanks though, definitely learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the whole `validate` function with a bit of a simpler check:

```
function validate() {
    var blankInputs = inputs.filter(function() {
        return this.value === ''; 
    });

    isValid = blankInputs.length === 0; // If there are none, the form is valid

} // close validate()
```

Please note the use of the strict equality operator, `===`.  It is good practice to pretty much always use this instead of `==`, but this is especially the case for values that act falsy (evaluate to false when you say `if (value)`).  `==` can give you some very unexpected behavior in these cases.